# Acceleration to velocity with coordinate $x$

Tags: physics

Can someone please help me in finding the formula used to get the answer to this question?

> An object moves along $x$-axis. In any coordinate $x$, the acceleration is $a=x^4$ (SI units). If the object goes from rest in $x=1$m, what velocity it will get at $x=2$m?
>   \begin{align*}
> A)\quad 4.59 \textrm{ m/s}\\
> B)\quad 3.52 \textrm{ m/s}\\
> C)\quad 2.47 \textrm{ m/s}\\
> D)\quad 5.66 \textrm{ m/s}\\
> E)\quad 1.41 \textrm{ m/s}\\
> \end{align*}

Answer **B** is the correct answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $v=\frac{dx}{dt}$ is the velocity at time $t$, we have
$$\frac{dv}{dt}=x^4.$$
There is a standard trick for solving this kind of DE. Multiply both sides by $v$. We get
$$v\frac{dv}{dt}=vx^4=x^4\frac{dx}{dt}.$$
Now we can integrate  with repect to $t$. On the left, we get $\frac{1}{2}v^2$, and on the right we get $\frac{1}{5}x^5 +C$. Thus
$$\frac{1}{2}v^2=\frac{1}{5}x^5 +C.$$
Use your initial condition to find that $C=-\frac{1}{5}$.  Now we know $v^2$ at position $x$.

Comment: Thank you, finally I get to the answer! So a formula to this type of problem can be: 1/2*v^2=integrate(a,x)+C. First we replace v and x with the initial condition to get C. Then we replace C, and x with the second state of initial condition right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. In your case we end up with $v^2=\frac{2}{5}(x^5-1)$, which is $12.4$ at $x=2$. Now take the square root.

Comment: Yes I get it, thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  Think about the relationship between velocity and acceleration in terms of calculus.

Let $v(x)$ be the velocity at position $x$; $a(x)$ be the acceleration at position $x$:

$$\int a(x)\ dx=v(s)+C,\ a(x)=v(x)\frac{d}{dx}$$

Comment: I can't get to this answer. If the acceleration was according to time, v=integrate(a,t) will do it, but I can't understand with positions..